# Freeradius proxy non EAP to EAP

Tags: freeradius

I have Freeradius as a proxy working fine with MSCHAPv2. However, I now have to use EAP to encrypt to the home server. How can I configure freeradius to proxy non EAP MSCHAPv2 to EAP with MSCHAPv2?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, FreeRADIUS cannot currently act as an EAP client, only as an EAP server.